# Actual answer is 11100 but we got 00111,how to reverse this

Tags: python, binary, reverse

```
b=[]
def number(num):
    if num==0:
        return
    if num%2==0:
        print("0")
        a=num/2
    else:
        num//2==0
        print("1")
        a=num//2
    return number(a)
number(28)
```

ans:
0
0
1
1
1

Comment: What does this part do? `num//2==0`

Comment: don't use `print` but assemble an object (string, list) that you return in the end

Comment: Add the result to a string say, `s` and use `s[::-1]`

Comment: @HarunYilmaz devides number and stores as integer, not float.

Comment: Rather use existing funstions. "{0:b}".format(28)

Comment: @GedasMiksenas Yep, I know the operator but the statement here has no effect since it is only a comparison.

Answer (score 0):

```
b = []
def number(num):
    if num == 0:
        return b[::-1]
    else:
        if num % 2 == 0:
            b.append("0")
        else:
            b.append("1")
        return number(num // 2)
```

Result: reversed array of binary answer, that you can join or do something else with.

```
print(number(28))

Output: ['1', '1', '1', '0', '0']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing binary to decimal then:
try this one line code

```
print(bin(28)[2:])
```

if you want a proper function then:

```
def DecimalToBinary(decimal):       
    if decimal > 1: 
        DecimalToBinary(decimal // 2)
    
    print(decimal % 2, end = '')

a = DecimalToBinary(28)
```